# Sphinx with PydataSphinxTheme: make autoattribute and automethod create headings without class prefix in the page contents

Tags: python-sphinx, autodoc

I am using Sphinx with PydataSphinxTheme. I created a custom class template which goes over all the attributes and methods of a class and uses autodoc to document them, like so:

```
*****************
Attribute details
*****************
{% for item in attributes %}
.. autoattribute:: {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Here, `{{ item }}` is only the name of the method, not the method name with the class prefix. I ommited some formatting from the template, but this is the main gist.

The result is that, if I have a class called `MyClass` with a method called `myMethod`, the method will be documented as `myMethod`, but the page contents navbar on the right will still contain `MyClass.myMethod`.

I want it to say only `myMethod` because it is obvious what the containing class is.

It seems that the `automethod` directive creates these page contents entries.

I have the `add_module_names = False` options in `conf.py` already set.

Figures:

1. method name in the body of the page

[image]

2. method names in the page contents

[image]